# Software for directory integrity

Tags: backup, diff

I keep a directory on my home server with all of my important files on it. I want to make offline backups of this directory. But as I add and modify file, I also want to be able to make comparisons between different backups and the current version in a "diff" style. In particular, I want to see which files have been added, which have been deleted, and which have been modified (although it's not important for me to see the file-level diffs).

I know that rsync has this kind of functionality sort-of built into it for doing its job, but it doesn't seem to expose it directly. I also know what I'm looking for is an implementation of a Merkle tree.

Does anyone have any recommendations for lightweight software that can do this kind of directory diff?

Comment: Look into backup software like `restic` or `borgbackup`.

Comment: These programs store the backup in a deduplicated "database", either locally or remotely. So it's not really a solution if you need the backup readable as ordinary files.  They both provide the ability to compare between backups though.  `restic` currently does not provide compression of backups, but `borgbackup` does.  I'm not writing this as an answer, because an answer should ideally contain an example.

Comment: You may also want to look at a version control system such as Mercurial (perhaps with the TortoiseHg gui) or git (perhaps with one of the gui listed at https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis). They make it easy to see which files have been added / deleted / modified, and do offline backups. (But they do a bunch of other stuff, so may be a overkill).